# Is it acceptable to use software which incidentally blocks ads?

Tags: halacha, technology, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, internet, gezel-stealing

A question on this site on [whether ad-blocking software is permissible](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14396/581) suggests that the answer is that it probably, but not definitely, is acceptable.

I don't use ad-blocking software myself, but I do use two programs developed for security reasons (NoScript and RequestPolicy) which have the incidental effect of blocking most ads. How would you reason about the acceptability of such software?

Comment: WADR to the KR cited on the other question, the tzad that there is a "tnai" when you come to the site is utter nonsense. No normal person thinks they are consenting to such a tnai when they enter a website, so you obviously can't say that it's "implicit." There is nothing wrong with using your programs.

Comment: I assume that makes sense to someone. [Necessary context](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5284697#5284697).

Comment: *Loose translation of @DovF's comment:* With all due respect to the "Kalashnikover_Rebbe" [username] cited on the other question, the argument that there is a stipulation when you come to the site is utter nonsense. No normal person thinks they are consenting to such a stipulation when they enter a website, so you obviously can't say that it's "implicit." There is nothing wrong with using your programs.

Comment: @msh210. In other words, Ad blocking software is perfectly acceptable, with no doubt at all, therefore software which only incidentally blocks ads is absolutely definitely acceptable and this isn't an interesting question. Am I interpreting that correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incidentally blocking ads would only be prohibited if installing intentionally ad-blocking software is prohibited. However, based on [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14676/2091), that is not the case, and ad-blocking software is permitted. I myself asked this question to Rabbi Hershel Schechter some time ago, and he too thought it was permissible. Thus, incidentally blocking ads would be permissible as well.