# browsing sites with significant probability of forbidden pictures like youtube

Tags: halacha, internet, shemirat-eynayim

sometimes when browsing youtube for interesting videos, it is inevitable to sometimes encounter some lewd pictures.

would this make it forbidden to browse sites like youtube according to halacha?

the question is not about general internet use but about using (without necessity) sites with high liability of bumping into lewd pictures like youtube or the like.

please source.

Comment: Same with walking outside in the summer

Comment: @DoubleAA no choice

Comment: If you think that matters it should be in your question....

Comment: Who said no choice? Surely you need your Rabbi's permission to watch Youtube just as you need one to go outside in the summer.

Comment: @AlBerko no choice refers to walking outside in the summer. but would watching youtube stuff out of curiosity of all the interesting videos there be ok or not

Comment: Depends who you ask, there are communities where Internet is forbidden, some where it is allowed only for work, some only with filters, some where everyone does what they want. I am afraid this question is very opinion-based, different people will have different opinions, all "correct"

Comment: @mbloch asking about youtube or the like

Comment: @michael the same is true. It depends. Depends if you are watching alone or in a public place. If you are one to move on when watching borderline content or if it will entice you to look at further forbidden sites. If you are a man or a woman. Old or young. This is a question for a rav or a friend that knows you well

Comment: Dupe? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75769/9682

Comment: @DonielF question not about general internet. everyone agrees porn sites are not allowed. question is about gray area sites like youtube

Comment: @michael Isn’t this just a subset of that, then?

Comment: @DonielF dont think so. asking about the gray area sites with significant probability of landing on some lewd pics like utube

Comment: @michael Isn’t that, like, 90% of the Internet, when you consider ads?

Comment: -1 for 1. "Isn't it what the whole internet about?" 2. How do you rate probabilities? 3. It is surely a duplicate. Filtering the Internet is one big question, I think. 4. You should start using Capital letters sometimes.

Comment: @DonielF:  Perhaps the answer to the ads problem is to [install an ad blocker](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17621/does-halacha-require-me-to-install-ad-blocker-software).  I use [uBlock Origin](https://ublockorigin.com/), which is perhaps one of the fastest and lightest ad blockers available nowadays.  It's free and open-source software.

Answer (score 3):

I had a talk on this topic with R' Chaim Weiss in Jerusalem. He told me that Shmirat Eynayim is not different from putting air-bags in your car - both serve to protect you from overriding serious prohibitions.

As those examples are preventive measures, not transgressions by themselves, one should contact a Rabbi on his personal considerations: strengths, weaknesses, benefits or losses, just as one has to consult a Rabbi on all other dangers - air/water pollution, smoking, using public transportation (rush hours), going out on vacation etc.

As a computer guy, I'm asked all the time to install a proper internet filter for my Haredi clients. And I always tell them that I'm not a Posek and they need to consult their own Rebbe to pick a suitable filter for them, like Rimon, Nativ, Etrog, Netfree etc. Same is true for the Kosher phones bonanza, where every Haredi Beis Din (in Israel at least) has its own filtering company (do they also report to the Rebbis?).

Comment: thanks but not asking about general internet use. see edit

Comment: If you delay installing a filter until they ask a rabbi which filter to use, there's a risk that they might never get to the matter.  It might be best to offer them the option of installing a strict filter right away.  Later on, if they have time, they can ask a rabbi whether to keep that filter or change to a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure about the source (it was one of the many articles you encounter on chabad.org, would take a while to find that one but if you're interested I might take the search) but it's pretty much the same with vile thoughts (and oh boy, do I have lots of them):

'It's one thing if a bird flies over your head. It's an entire other thing if the bird nests on your head' (a quote from said article).

Same applies to those stupid youtube videos where some people decide to whore themselves out a bit to grab some attention (in form of views one might say) with these primitive thumbnails and titles. Indeed, it is inevitable to come across one of the aforementioned toxic thumbnails in the 'recommended' tab. But if you just see it blurry and quickly, without focusing on it and scrolling right past that garbage, it will be alright. Just as Double AA said in the comments, walking outside in summer is pretty much the same. You might see it from your peripheral vision: don't turn your head in that case. It's pointless, I think. Especially if you're married.

Recognize the 'threats' early on and don't pay attention to them after you understood what it is about.

Again, if you insist on the source (chabad.org article) I'll do the search. But bear in mind it's a rav who wrote it. Don't know if that suits you or if you exclusively accept talmudic/halacha sources.