# Is it allowed to fool adblock recognition mechanism

Tags: halacha, internet, gezel-stealing

This is a continuation of [Is ad-blocker software permissible?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/is-ad-blocker-software-permissible)

Nowadays more and more sites are detecting if someone uses ad blocking software . If they detect it, they don't serve the content of the site.

Is it allowed to install software or take other actions to fool these mechanisms, so that we can still see the content?

It could be that i am allowed to use an adblocker because of the fact that the web site owner can detect that i am using it and can block the site for me, but at the time i start to fool the detection mechanism it could be more chomur.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be the same?

Comment: This is my question if it is the same

Comment: I asked a dayan and he told me that there Ud indeed no difference

Comment: Thank you for telling us!  Could you please repost that comment as an answer, below?