# Lying on Websites

Tags: internet, sheker-false

Is there any halachic issue with lying on websites? For example, if a site requires you to be 21 and asks, “Are you over 21?” And you're not, but select “yes”. Is there any problem with doing so?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82889/is-block-evasion-a-sin

Comment: 1. Is it considered Machshovoh or Dibur or Maase or else? 2. Is this action toward a person or a server? 3. Where do you think it is different from the real-life situations? Do you mean *"especially on the Web"*?

Comment: While the topic is fascinating, following my previous comment I'd vote to put the Q on hold as too broad - there are tens of different actions on the Web with different Halochos.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this article](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Prohibition_to_Lie#cite_ref-48) will give insight into possible answers to you questions.

Generally, one should avoid lying as the Torah instructs (Shemos 23:7), מִדְּבַר שֶׁקֶר תִּרְחָק.

Yet, there are exceptions when for a purpose. For example, (from that article):

One who is shipping fragile objects such as matzah can write the word "glass" on the box in order that it should be dealt with properly. (But it is better to simply write "fragile".

See also, [this article](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5761-shoftim/).

It seems that the lenient view would allow answering "yes" on such a site if it will not cause anyone a loss. The more strict approach would prohibit it even if it causes no loss (so as not to express a bad trait of dishonesty), unless there is a specific benefit that outweighs this concern, such as to protect someone's dignity.